# Closed points and rational points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, galois-extensions, galois-representations

If $X$ is a $k$-scheme of finite type with $k$ a field, there is a surjective map $\gamma$ from the set of $\overline{k}$-rational points of $X \times_{\mathrm{Spec}(k)}\mathrm{Spec}(\overline{k})$, with $\overline{k}$ an algebraic closure of $k$, to the set of closed points of $X$. Each closed point of $X$ corresponds to a $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{k}/k)$-orbit of $\overline{k}$-rational points.

If I remember well, this is not true for general $k$-schemes. What are some ineteresting examples where the map $\gamma$ is *not* surjective ?

Comment: @SamStreeter : indeed ! -- corrected, thanks.

Comment: According to Proposition 5.4. p. 120 in Görtz–Wedhorn, if $X$ be a $k$-scheme **locally of finite type** then there is a bijection between the set of $Aut(\overline k/k)$-orbits in $X(\overline k)$ and the set of closed points of $X$.

Comment: @Watson : I am aware of that result, but what if $X$ is not locally of finite type ?

Comment: Take $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{C}(x)$ as a scheme over $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{C}$.